# Ajax Post method issue with passing huge data

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp

folks

we are facing a strange issue with jquery ( 1.8.3) and we are using cakePHP

[image]

as per the image

Our assumption is we are sending the data( about 500 +)  with ajax call in POST method.

we are having this issue in all the major browsers.

[image]

as above( in chrome) , we are getting this error in console we passed 618 destinations in ajax call.

let us know the work around to solve this problem.

My ajax call is as below

```
function validate_test() {
        $("#btn1").empty();
        var ele = document.getElementById('frm_searchDateFrom').value;
        var ele2 = document.getElementById('frm_searchDateTo').value;
        var sub_url = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/', true); ?>';
        var url = sub_url + "admin/reports/check_originator/" + ele +"/"+ ele2 +"/"+ $("#destination").val();
        alert(url);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            url: url,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var el = $("select#btn1").multiselect();
                var d;
                var results=data.split(",");
                for(d=0;d<results.length;d++) {
                var d;
                var v = results[d], opt = $('<option />', {
                    value: v,
                    text: v
                });
                opt.appendTo( el );
                el.multiselect('refresh');
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: plz add an image of "Headers" tab

Comment: The request URI is too long (usually max 2048 after the protocol). The data isn't sent in the POST body it looks like. Are you sure it's a POST AND you're sending all the data in the body?

Answer (score 0):

In your JQuery Ajax method instead of posting all those details as url query para meter send by wrapping those details in a object.

```
function validate_test() {
        $("#btn1").empty();
        var ele = document.getElementById('frm_searchDateFrom').value;
        var ele2 = document.getElementById('frm_searchDateTo').value;
        var sub_url = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/', true); ?>';
        var url = sub_url + "admin/reports/check_originator/";
        var formdata=ele +"/"+ ele2 +"/"+ $("#destination").val();//put form data's in an object 
        alert(url);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data:formdata,//send the form data object in post 
            url: url,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var el = $("select#btn1").multiselect();
                var d;
                var results=data.split(",");
                for(d=0;d<results.length;d++) {
                var d;
                var v = results[d], opt = $('<option />', {
                    value: v,
                    text: v
                });
                opt.appendTo( el );
                el.multiselect('refresh');
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Also refer this fiddle(not mine):
http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/